# Using Webview2 and VB.Net, how can I do to save PDF in clicking on PDF icon or pressing Ctrl+S keys?

Tags: vb.net, pdf, download, webview2

I search to save a `PDF` file displayed on a `WebView2` control using `VB.Net`.

Currently, I use following code to display `PDF` file

```
Imports Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices
Imports System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.TrackBar

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call InitializeAsync()
    End Sub

    Async Sub InitializeAsync()
        Await wv.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
        wv.Source = New Uri("https://recherche.wallonie.be/files/E_Kiosque/01.ATHENA/Athena%20PDF/358.pdf")
    End Sub

    Private Sub wv_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles wv.NavigationCompleted
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        Call ClickOnSaveIcon()
    End Sub

    Async Sub ClickOnSaveIcon()
        Dim sButtonCmd = "document.getElementById('download').click();"
        Dim task = Await wv.ExecuteScriptAsync(sButtonCmd)
    End Sub

End Class
```

After loading `PDF` file in `WebView2`, when `PDF` file has been completely loaded, I call `ClickOnSaveIcon()` method to click on icon using `Javascript`.

But `Save PDF` Dialog (that I can see in pressing Ctrl+S manually) is never displayed !

I have also tried with

```
    Async Sub ClickOnSaveIcon()
        My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("^(S)", True)
    End Sub
```

But I obtain same result !

How can I do to save downloaded `PDF` file on my Windows 11 PC ?

Answer (score 1):

The solution of your problem is following

```
Async Sub ClickOnSaveIcon()
    My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("^(s)", True)
End Sub
```

The key combination to save PDF file is `CTRL+S`. It is equivalent to `^s` using `SendKey()` function.

Key combination `^S` (S in uppercase) is equivalent to `CTRL+SHIFT+S` that on `WebView2` is equivalent to `Web Capture` action !

All WebView shortcuts are defined on [Learn Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/browser-features)